# Locus of a point on a sliding rod leaned against a wall

Tags: analytic-geometry, locus

A rod AB of length 3 rests on a wall as follows:

P is a point on AB such that AP:PB=1:2. If the rod slides along the wall, then the locus of the point lies in $4x^2+y^2=4$- Prove it.

My attempt

Although I could only guess that the locus will be an ellipse by intuition and figure but no mathematical basis to prove my point. Please please help. I am clueless here.

Comment: Type your question so we can read it, please.  If it's too much trouble to type, it's too much trouble to answer.

Comment: @Saradamani: use a scanner. If you don't have one, download an app that does the job.

Comment: Yes but I have already corrected it. No need for all that downvote as I won't be able to ask questions, which I need utterly, for 3 consecutive days if umpteen downvotes are cast. I was barred from asking for 3 days a week ago due to these downvotes. You mention it, I correct it thats it. I stay in such a place where there is not a proper guide to help me with math within the radius of 100 kms. So please understand.

Comment: I have no idea as to why this is off topic@ Alex Francisco, @jvdhooft, Leucippus, Shailesh, cansomeonehelpmeout. Where on earth do you find it off topic? This question is a part of analytic geometry? Is it wrong? or Locus. Is it wrong? And I could not solve the problem. I tried using some methods but I do not know how to draw figures in LATEX, thats why I took the snapshot. So which part was off topic? And OnceUponACrinoid- a user has already solved it beautifully. So why so much fuss I do not understand. Only because you have the liberty to cast someone off from your 'elite' is strange!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Choose the origin as the intersection of the two walls.

Let $A=(0,a)$ and $B=(b,0)$ be the coordinates of the end points of the ladder in a general configuration.

Then, the point $P$ is $(\frac{b}{3}, \frac{2a}{3})$. (Why?)

As the ladder slips around, $a$ and $b$ can change but since the length is $3$, we must have 
$$ a^2+b^2=9$$ (Why?)

Substitute $x=\frac{b}{3}$ and $y=\frac{2a}{3}$ into the above constraint to get your required locus.

Comment: A billion upvotes for your answer. Please give me your brain for a month. I will return it to you after that.Ohh! such an answer!!

Answer (score 0):

The question becomes quite easy while assuming the polar format for solving the question and finding the locus. The given point "P", has an x co-ordinate of l/3cos(k), where k is the angle made by the rod with the horizontal, and length of rod is taken l, similarly the y co-ordinate of the rod is 2l/3sin(k), as now 3x/l is cos(k), and 3y/2l is sin(k); now squaring and adding for achieving the pythagorean identity, we get 9x^2/l^2 + 9y^2/4l^2 =1, as l=3, hence the locus decomposes to 4x^2+y^2=4.

sorry for the sluggish explanation I am a beginner and unaware of using Math Jax.